# Dynamic data manipulation in word online

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js

I am trying to build a task-pane add-in for word online which can do mail merge like desktop office. Now I understand that word online does not support mail merge out of the box, so I thought about the following steps -

1. Create a template (DOTX) using desktop office which will contain Region or something like a merge field etc. Upload the template to one drive.
2. Open a blank doc and add a task pane add-in in word online. This is temporary step for now.
3. Click a button on the add-in.
4. This click will stream the template (DOTX) from server using an app service call.
5. Render the stream into word online web page.
6. Edit and save.
7. Close word online and reopen.
8. Click the doc link.
9. This will render the doc in word online.
10. Add the add-in in the task pane (temp step).
11. Click edit button.
12. Call app service to fetch the latest merge data source.
13. Traverse through the word xml and replace the values corresponding to the region or special keys.
14. Re-render the doc.

My users will have E1 subscription of office 365.

Is this thought process logical and achievable with word online? Thanks in advance!...

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is much more complicated than it needs to be. Word Online supports Add-ins created using the JavaScript APIs, as supported by the information in this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn833104.aspx

It should be possible for you to create the "template" on the Desktop (Word 2013 or 2016 is required - but only 2016 supports the current full scope of the JS API) and "insert" your add-in, which links it to the document. Opening the document in Word online should automatically load the add-in, that can then link to the data source and fill in the data.

As data targets ("merge fields"), I recommend you use Content Controls.